"..., with aftershocks continued..."
This is from a news article.

Strong shaking was felt in Taipei, the capital, some 100 miles away,
with aftershocks continued for roughly two hours.

Automatic substitution in Google Docs suggests "continued" be substituted with "continuing".
Is it right?

Yes. The appropriate verb form after 'with' is the gerund.

@MichaelHarvey Thank you very much.

My guess is the article was written and edited hastily and "continued" might be left over from an earlier version of the sentence, like "... and aftershocks continued," or "... away. Aftershocks continued..."

@AndyBonner Thank you very much.

The choice of verb form is wrong.
Since, from general knowledge of earthquakes, we know that "aftershocks" is the subject of "continue" you should choose an active form of the verb. You could either use a participle "with aftershocks continuing...." or use an independent clause (which would be in the past tense) "and aftershocks continued..."
The past participle (which for this verb has exactly the same form as the past tense) would be passive.  "aftershocks were continued by someone" and this is obviously not the intended meaning.

Thank you very much.
